# Nothing appear in the console on Eclipse when using pthread

Tags: c, eclipse, console, pthreads

I've this code which basically create a thread and wait it end. This thread print only Hello, "flush" is only here to clean the buffer. I work on Eclipse on Windows 8.1 (yes it's bad, I know)

```
void *first(void *id)
{
   printf("Hello!\n");
   fflush(stdout);
   return NULL;
}


int main(void){

    pthread_t threads;
    printf("test\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    pthread_create(&threads, NULL, first, NULL);
    pthread_join(threads, NULL);

    printf("test2\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    //pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

In this configuration the console stay blanck when a launch this code in Eclipse in Run mode.
If I launch it in Debug mode I've this in the console:

```
test
Hello!
test2
```

If I quote:

```
    //pthread_create(&threads, NULL, first, NULL);
    //pthread_join(threads, NULL);
```

And I launch it in Run mode I've this in the console:

```
test
test2
```

So the question is, did someone know why when I use pthread_create there is nothing in the console in Run mode but there is something in Debug mode? And how to have something in the console when I use pthread_create in Run mode?

Comment: You should receive the same result for debug and non-debug ("run", "release") build.

Comment: Did you add `-pthread` to the *compiler*'s options? (Please note, that this is **different** from the *linker*'s option `-lpthread`).

Comment: I know that I should have the same result but it's not. I tried with -pthread but it's the same

Comment: What result do you get when building on the command line, this is without Eclipse being involved?